# self.manager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil) error

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I use `self.manager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)` I get this:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

I don't know how to use `scanForPeripheralsWithServices`. Can't the first parameter be nil?

System: iOS 9.2.1

Comment: How did you declare `manager`? Is something like `let manager: ClassName!`?

Comment: var manager: CBCentralManager!, but if I remove the ! at the end, then appears error: Class 'ViewController' has no initializers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nil` for both the two parameters. The problem is not the method, but your `manager`. Double check if you declare your `manager` as `SOMETHING!` with a `!` mark at the end. This will cause the error if it's `nil` when you use it.

Comment: If I remove the ! at the end, then appears error: Class 'ViewController' has no initializers.

Comment: I found the reason, in func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber), I use 'print("name: \(peripheral.name!)")', rewrite to 'print("name: \(peripheral.name)")', problem solved...and thank you~~